# Exclude one file from a password protected subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I've this .htaccess to protect a subdomain.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/xxx/dev.xxx.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Dev"
require valid-user
```

How can I exclude only one file from this protection.
Then this file could be accesible without password protection

Comment: If the file doesn't need protecting it's best to move it outside that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `Satisfy Any` and a special `Allow` that lets certain requests through without a password check. So in your htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/protected-dir/no_protect_file.php norequire_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /home/xxx/dev.xxx.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Dev"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

If a request is made for `http://your.domain.com/protected-dir/no_protect_file.php`, the `SetEnvIf` matches and the `norequire_auth` environment variable is set. The auth part checks for it to allow it to pass through without requiring a password.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new directory outside the password protected one and create a symlink to the file you want to be unprotected and distribute the URL to the non-protected library instead of the protected one.